# Reflection does not respect @ symbol with reserved keyword classes

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a situation where the following class is created by the code generator. I don't have a control of how it generates.

```
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
                        
    namespace MyClasses
    {
        
        public class @event { };
        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            
            @event e = (@event) (Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "MyClasses.@event")).Unwrap();
            Console.WriteLine("Created.");
        }
    }
    }
```

As you can see that it sees the class name with `event` reserved word, and it adds @ sign. After that it tries to create an object of the same using reflection by passing @ symbol, which reflection rejects.

If I replace it with
   `@event e = (@event) (Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "MyClasses.event")).Unwrap();`

It works.

What is the possible solution here? I don't have a control on how it adds @ or uses @ ? I understand that reflection does not know about @ symbol being added. Thus, there has to be a way for the reflection to ignore @symbol while creating an object because technically you cannot have @ in your variable or a class name.

Fiddler link:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/wBs7GA

Comment: '@' is *not* part of the name of the member `event`. It's an escape character that you would need in C# source code in order to compile  a reserved word in a name. The problem is the code generator, which you should try to change, even though you said that you can't.

Comment: To be elaborate @JeremyLakeman 's comment: replace `"MyClasses.@event"` by `"MyClasses.event"`

Comment: completely understand @JeremyLakeman and I just wanted to see what are the other options out there except changing something that I have a less control on.